# Bind the .datepicker() to new input elements

Tags: jquery, datepicker, onload

I am trying to add the datepicker to input elements created on the fly.I understood the usage of .on() or .live() function but I can't find the right event to bind them on:

Trying to use `.on` since `live()` got depercated I succeded the following:
On input field click it's turned into a datepicker input

```
 $("#container").on("click", ".date", function(){
        $(this).datepicker()
  });
```

But I need this on the `onload` event which does not exist on inputs.

Comment: You would have to bind it after the element has been created.

Comment: *So this works fine on all date inputs:

 `$('input.date').live().datepicker();`* No it does not work, you are seeing things. The `.live()` does not do anything there.

Comment: Can't you bind it on 'hover'?